# Moving @ElementCollection to @Embeddable class not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to move an `@ElementCollection` annotated field from my `@Entity` class into a different class that I annotated with `@Embeddable`. When the field is in the entity, Hibernate will issue the proper INSERT statements. When the field is moved to the `@Embeddable` class, no INSERT statements are generated.

So this works:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity<MyEntityId> {
  @ElementCollection
  @OrderColumn
  private List<Double> doubles;
}
```

But this does not:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity<MyEntityId> {
  @Embedded
  private Doubles doubles;
}

@Embeddable
public class Doubles {
  @ElementCollection
  @OrderColumn
  private List<Double> doubles;
}
```

There is no exception when saving a `MyEntity` instance (and flushing the EntityManager). If I disable creating the appropriate table in Flyway, the Hibernate validation does trigger a "missing table [my_entity_doubles]" error, so Hibernate does seem to correct interpret the setup.

Using Spring Boot 2.3.4 that uses Hibernate 5.4.21.

UPDATE: There is a reproducible testcase at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/so-64336648

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why. But assigning with a collection works.

```
@Embeddable
public class Doubles {
  @ElementCollection
  private List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem and indeed it works if you initialize the collection. I haven't found any explanation or documentation of why it should be initiated. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

As it stated in the JPA specification (see **2.5 Embeddable Classes** section):

> An embeddable class (including an embeddable class within another embeddable class) may contain a collection of a basic type or other embeddable class. Direct or indirect circular containment dependencies among embeddable classes are not permitted.

And simple example (based on Hibernate 5.4.21).

Assuming that we have the following schema:

```sql
create table T1_MY_ENTITY
(
   tm_id int not null,

   primary key (tm_id)
);

insert into T1_MY_ENTITY values (1);

create table T1_MY_COLL
(
   tc_tm_id int not null,
   tc_ord_id int not null,
   tc_code varchar(100),

   foreign key (tc_tm_id) references T1_MY_ENTITY(tm_id)
);

insert into T1_MY_COLL values (1, 1, 'CL1'), (1, 0, 'CL2');
```

and the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T1_MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "tm_id")
   private Long id;

   @Embedded
   private Doubles dou;
   
   // constructor, getters, setters
}

@Embeddable
public class Doubles
{
   @OrderColumn(name = "tc_ord_id")
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "T1_MY_COLL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tc_tm_id"))
   @Column(name = "tc_code")
   private List<String> colls;

   // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

the following code:

```java
MyEntity myEntity =  entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 1L);
myEntity.getDou().getColls().add("CL5");
entityManager.merge(myEntity);
```

will generate insert:

```
19:51:29,612 DEBUG SQL:128 - 
    /* insert collection
        row com.my.hibernate.entities.MyEntity.dou.colls */ insert 
        into
            TEST_SCHEMA.T1_MY_COLL
            (tc_tm_id, tc_ord_id, tc_code) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert collection
        row com.my.hibernate.entities.MyEntity.dou.colls */ insert 
        into
            TEST_SCHEMA.T1_MY_COLL
            (tc_tm_id, tc_ord_id, tc_code) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
19:51:29,612 TRACE ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:83 - Registering statement [/* insert collection row com.my.hibernate.entities.MyEntity.dou.colls */ insert into TEST_SCHEMA.T1_MY_COLL (tc_tm_id, tc_ord_id, tc_code) values (?, ?, ?)]
19:51:29,612 TRACE BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
19:51:29,613 TRACE BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [2]
19:51:29,613 TRACE BasicBinder:64 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [CL5]
```

So, It looks like your problem lies in the other plane.

**UPDATE**: As for your [test case](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/so-64336648/blob/main/src/test/java/com/wimdeblauwe/so/embeddableelementcollection/MyEntity2RepositoryTest.java#L44), please try to correct it in the following way:

```java
@Test
void test() {
   MyEntity2 entity = new MyEntity2();
   Doubles doubles = new Doubles();
   doubles.setDoubles(List.of(1.0, 1.5));

   entity.setDoubles(doubles); // It was absent !!!

   repository.save(entity);

   entityManager.flush();

   assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT count(*) FROM my_entity2_doubles", Long.class)).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

Comment: This is not the behaviour I see. I created an example at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/so-64336648

Comment: Sorry that my testcase had such a glaring mistake. Unfortunately, that was not the exact issue I had. I pushed a new commit that shows it now. It seems the problem only appears when my entity extends an abstract class that is annotated as `@MappedSuperClass`. Would be really grateful if you could have another look. Starting to wonder if it might be a Hibernate bug.

Comment: Your mapping looks very abstract. I can not imagine data model that require it. You use `MyEntity3Id` that extends `AbstractEntityId<Long>` and `AbstractEntityId` mapped as `@MappedSuperclass`. From the other side, your `AbstractEntity` defines `T id` mapped as `@EmbeddedId` and this requires that `T` should be `@Embeddable`. I guess this is a mistake.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what database schema will generated by this mapping.